# JQUERY show html div on Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

Is it possible to show html tag on jquery fullcalendar.
Ex:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>

$('#a').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','white');
  }
);
```

Fullcalendar plugin
http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/562/

Comment: i don't understand what u mean... this code works. what is fullcalendar?

Comment: What this code has to do with fullCalendar?

Comment: I am sorry i just edited my question :)

Comment: what do you mean by `show html div on it`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out by using following code hope it helps someone

javascript

```
  eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
                var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:auto;height:auto;background:#FFB347;position:absolute;z-index:10001;font-size: 3em;">' + calEvent.title +'</div>';

                $('#myResults').html(calEvent.title);


                $("body").append(tooltip);
                $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
                    $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
                    $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
                    $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
                }).mousemove(function(e) {
                    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
                    $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
                });
            }
```

HTML

```
<div id="myResults"></div>
```